# Javascript: Decimals still being allowed in regex check for numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following to test for only numbers but I am having an issue with decimals still passing the test `/^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d+$/.test(v)` .  Am I using this incorrectly to test for that?

Comment: Your regex allows a decimal here `\.{0,1}`

Comment: There's a literal dot in there... - Why would this not accept a number with decimals?

Comment: Your pattern has `\.{0,1}\d+` which allows the decimal...Why do you expect them to fail the test?

Comment: You can simplify your regex by using `?` instead of `{0,1}`.  Show us your test data and expected results.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only integers, use:

```
/^-?\d+$/.test(v)
```

--- EXPLANATION

**^** - start of the string

**-?** - minus in the start, `?` means can be but not necessary

**\d** - any number (including zero)

**+** - the last expression (=any number) can repeat more then once

**$** - end of the string

Comment: I update the answer, and add the explanation

Comment: `[1-9]\d*` would prevent me from literally entering just `0` which is a valid number

Comment: `^(?:0|-?[1-9]\d*)$` would be more appropriate.

Comment: you are right. still thing better like this `/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)$/.test(v)`, since after all `-0` is also should be valid

Comment: but in the end i think any kind of leading zero is valid.. try to put in the console `var n = 0002` or `parseInt('045')`..

Comment: if you look on the original expression, they not care about leading zero